# Android kotlin overriding interface methods inside onCreateView() method

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am new to Kotlin. I have an interface containing two method definitions:

```
fun onSuccess(result: T)
fun onFailure(e: Exception)
```

Now, in my fragment I have implemented this interface and want to use these methods inside as:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
     ..................
     ..................
     override fun onSuccess(result: String) {}
     override fun onFailure(e: Exception) {}
}
```

In java we can use with @override but here I am getting the error 'Modifier 'override' is not applicable to local function'. I am working in kotlin for last 2-3 days and I love it. But some time small issues taking some time to debug.

Answer (score 12):

You need to implement the interface on your fragment and move the overriding methods outside your onCreateView method.

class MyFragment : Fragment, MyInterface

You can't override methods inside a method. Another option is you can create an object expression demonstrated below

```
window.addMouseListener(object : MouseAdapter() {
    override fun mouseClicked(e: MouseEvent) {
        // ...
    }

    override fun mouseEntered(e: MouseEvent) {
        // ...
    }
})
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

Comment: This works If i declare the method outside. But my question is, if there is a way we can declare methods inside like java.

Comment: Updated the answer, you can't override methods inside another method in Java but you can create an object expression.